# Apply different configuration (globalization) settings for a sub directory

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to apply different settings (globalization) on a sub directory(~/MainSite/Forum/). For this purpose, I have created a configuration file under subdirectory ~/MainSite/Forum/web.config

But sub directory (~/MainSite/Forum/) always geting globalization settings from root configuration (~/MainSite/web.config) instead of its own configuration (~/MainSite/Forum/web.config) file.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in the root web.config:

```
  <location path="/MainSite/Forum/">
    <system.web>
      <globalization/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: yes, you are right, But i have already added globalization settings under <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> section. 

If I am mentioning another globalization setting for sub directory, it’s not working.  like 
<location path="Forum">
    <system.web>
      <globalization uiCulture="ar-SA"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>

In short, globalization settings only read one setting either from parent or sub location.